# Ruby DB Migration Error 'rake db:migrate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine

I am starting to play around with ruby and setting up my development environment.

I am referencing  [This Ruby on Rails 'Getting Started Guide'](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and am down to section 5.5 'Running a Migration'

The problem is when I run the following command

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error

```
C:\Users\someuser\RubymineProjects\my_app>rake db:migrate 
rake aborted!
SyntaxError:C:/Users/someuser/RubymineProjects/my_app/db/migrate/20140718160751_create_articles.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
  t.string :[title
             ^
C:/Users/someuser/RubymineProjects/my_app/db/migrate/20140718160751_create_articles.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting keyword_end
  t.text] :text
         ^
C:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you post your migration file? It should be `t.string :title`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have some extra brackets in your migration that don't belong there.  The migration should look like:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```